# Polite form of apology with tense form?

Tags: nuances, politeness

After missing an appointment, which would be more appropriate for asking for forgiveness or apologizing?

> ごめんなさい でした

or

> 本当にごめんね。ほんとうに　ごめんね

In particular, considering the difference between the two, which would be better to use for a 先生?

Comment: Have you looked at ごめんなさい threads: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E3%81%94%E3%82%81%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%81%84 ?

Comment: The question is not quite clear to me: did you miss the appointment, or will you miss it?

Comment: I have seen a few threads containing the use of apology. The context is for an apology, even though I gave notice ahead of time that I was not able to make the appointment. I want to make sure the polite form combined with tense is accurate.

Comment: Also the appointment was in the past.

Comment: What is the "tense form"?

Comment: ^ past が抜けてるとか...？Polite form of apology with **past** tense form? とか・・

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the best is:

> > 申｛もう｝し訳｛わけ｝ありませんでした。
> >     I'm very sorry (lit. 'there was no excuse').

Comment: If it’s in a less formal setting, すみませんでした would work as well.